# gradle not working well

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to add a library to my gradle but this library should be like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
}
```

but when I copy this code my whole program will changes like this
errors comes I really don't know why.

[image: Android errors]

Comment: clean and rebuild ?

Comment: Always use same(Compatible) version of android.support libraries

Comment: yea not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use same version of support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Then
**`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** your project

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
}
```